# Unable to get the content of webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I use `requests` to get a webpage but failed.

Here is my code:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
url = 'http://db.house.qq.com/index.php?mod=search&city=bj'
headers = {}
headers['authority'] = 'db.house.qq.com'
headers['method'] = 'GET'
headers['path'] = '/index.php?mod=search&city=bj'
headers['scheme'] = 'https'
headers['accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
headers['accept-encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br'
headers['accept-language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-HK;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,an;q=0.5'
headers['cookie'] = 'pgv_info=ssid=s9739254340; pgv_pvid=9743767040; ts_uid=2023229671; pac_uid=0_da940c972d7c0; h_uid=h592060229584922854; Hm_lvt_73f18bb34ff30f1061b904f30f86c5cb=1602238779; ts_refer=www.google.com/; ts_uid=6802299874; pgv_pvi=196710400; pgv_si=s9373821952; Hm_lpvt_73f18bb34ff30f1061b904f30f86c5cb=1602767734; hisuid=[%22h592060229584922854%22]; hisuin=[null]; feature={%2295%22:1%2C%2298%22:1}; ts_last=db.house.qq.com/index.php; ad_play_index=86'
headers['dnt'] = '1'
headers['sec-ch-ua'] = '"Chromium";v="86", "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"'
headers['sec-ch-ua-mobile'] = '?0'
headers['sec-fetch-dest'] = 'document'
headers['sec-fetch-mode'] = 'navigate'
headers['sec-fetch-site'] = 'none'
headers['upgrade-insecure-requests'] = '1'
headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res.encoding = res.apparent_encoding
print(soup.find('em', {'id':'search_result_num'}).text)#0, should be 3767
print('三湘印象·森林海尚城' in res.text)#False, should be True
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a tag.

Comment: I have attached the corresponding code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was generated by Javascript.(Not json.),I caught this url in developer tool.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://db.house.qq.com/index.php?mod=search&act=newsearch&city=bj&showtype=1&mod=search&city=bj'
# url = 'http://db.house.qq.com/index.php?mod=search&city=bj'
headers = {}
headers['authority'] = 'db.house.qq.com'
headers['method'] = 'GET'
headers['path'] = '/index.php?mod=search&city=bj'
headers['scheme'] = 'https'
headers['accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
headers['accept-encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br'
headers['accept-language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-HK;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,an;q=0.5'
headers['cookie'] = 'pgv_info=ssid=s9739254340; pgv_pvid=9743767040; ts_uid=2023229671; pac_uid=0_da940c972d7c0; h_uid=h592060229584922854; Hm_lvt_73f18bb34ff30f1061b904f30f86c5cb=1602238779; ts_refer=www.google.com/; ts_uid=6802299874; pgv_pvi=196710400; pgv_si=s9373821952; Hm_lpvt_73f18bb34ff30f1061b904f30f86c5cb=1602767734; hisuid=[%22h592060229584922854%22]; hisuin=[null]; feature={%2295%22:1%2C%2298%22:1}; ts_last=db.house.qq.com/index.php; ad_play_index=86'
headers['dnt'] = '1'
headers['sec-ch-ua'] = '"Chromium";v="86", "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"'
headers['sec-ch-ua-mobile'] = '?0'
headers['sec-fetch-dest'] = 'document'
headers['sec-fetch-mode'] = 'navigate'
headers['sec-fetch-site'] = 'none'
headers['upgrade-insecure-requests'] = '1'
headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
text = res.content.decode("unicode_escape") # escape this content.

print("三湘印象·森林海尚城" in text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
result = soup.find(id="search_result_page").find_all("a")[-1].text
print(re.search(r"search_result_list_num = (\d+);", result).group(1)) # use regex to find the amount of results.
```

Print:

```
True
3767
```

Comment: Thanks, jizhihaoSAMA. Can you show me how to get your url?

Comment: @Chan Press F12, turns to "Network", check the response in all the urls under JS request....